# Replicating Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am trying to download a Rails app from github and that make it work on my PC. I have read other posts that say you have to run `bundle install`, `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate`, I do everything but when I try to run `rake db:create` I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.3.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
D:/art-website/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
D:/art-website/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
D:/art-website/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
D:/art-website/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
D:/art-website/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
D:/art-website/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Please try to refrain from requesting urgent or special attention from volunteers here. All questions are of equal importance. Have you tried searching for this error?

Comment: First line of the error, it asks you to append 'bundle exec' to your rake commands. So have you tried:


1) `Bundle install`

2) `bundle exec rake db:create`

3) `bundle exec rake db:migrate`


?

Comment: just add `bundle exec` it will solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

### The cause

Your gem  `rake` has a conflicts in the version you have installed i.e. the gem `rake` your `Gemfile` requires is of version `10.3.2` while the gem you have on your machine has got version `10.4.2` and `10.3.2`.

### Solution

1. uninstall the gem of version `10.4.2`. `gem uninstall rake` would ask you for the version that has to be uninstalled, please select `10.4.2`
2. you may run the commands with `bundle exec` eg:- `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or `bundle exec rake db:create`
3. you may want to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) and use [Gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) as per the projects and its dependency gems. (I would personally prefer this way so that the projects of different version of gems would be clear and no need to worry about the conflicts gem versions)